# How use some JS libraries at DART in a non-Web scenario?

Tags: dart-js-interop

## First Ask

- I can't find info about how to import js file into a dart and run. (non-web)

> What info I known: 
> Using js_facade_gen to gen facades for TypeScript libraries, but it is need a html to import js.

```html
<head>
...
    <script type="application/javascript" src="./xxxx.js"></script>
```

Can you give me some ideas, thank you very much. 
ps:  if it is no code to write, it is wonderful

---

---

## More info(second)

```
some more info: 
pub.dev/packages/flutter_qjs
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jscore
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js
```

But they're running code, not libraries.

> Anyway, I don't have to be on the Web. But the problem remains difficult

Comment: you are aware that javascript  is specific to web environment and some libs work ONLY in browser not even node.js

Comment: I'm very sorry that I don't quite understand the relationship between what you said and my question.

Comment: If, in the UI, the response to events is not dependent on js. Or my UI is not controlled by JS. It's just a logical addition. Because it's a call in a different language, I think it's a bit like RPC, or callback.

Answer (score 0):

idea from

```sh
https://github.com/duyduong/interactive_webview
https://github.com/berberin/qrpay-sol
```

it can use a web as a runtime.